# Error reading pandas dataframe that was initially converted from pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have a problem opening a ex-spark Dataframe on a machine w/o pyspark.

Machine 1:

```
df = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://url.com:8000/data/project01/dflast.parquet")
print(df.count())
print(type(df))
df1 = df.toPandas()
print(type(df1))
pd.to_pickle(df1, 'df_last.pkl', compression='zip')
```

> ```
> 1200
>
> class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'
>
> class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
> ```

After that I download the pickle to my local machine, and trying to open it, and get an error

Machine 2:

`df = pd.read_pickle('./data/df_last.pkl', compression='zip')`

> ```
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'>
> ```

What is wrong? Why do i need to have pyspark if I've already converted it to pandas?

Comment: The short answer is "don't use pickle for data" and "don't pickle dataframes". It doesn't really solve your problem, but if you use a proper data format (or pretty much anything other than pickle) your problem becomes a non-problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I used csv and it helped.